# DataGrid row Background color MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Im using MVVM architecture and I want to change the row color in a datagrid.
The color of row depends on the item from the model.

so far I have this Code:

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) {
        Log4NetLog dataGridRow = e.Row.DataContext as Log4NetLog;
        if (highlight) {
            if (dataGridRow != null) {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(
                    dataGridRow.LogColour.Colour);
            }
        } else {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
}
```

As you can see, in the second Line I have to make an reference to a `Log4NetLog` which is in the model.

So how can I change the code to adapt the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Can you post more code for this? Where does highlight come from? To do this adapting an MVVM pattern, you can set a DataGridRow Template to modify the value of the Background colour based on a binding to a property in your DataContext ViewModel. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx.

Comment: highlight is just a boolean... you can just ignore it. its not imoportant

Comment: Ok, but essentially you need some property in your viewmodel which you can bind to, through a ValueConverter to return a colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your DataGrids ItemsSource is bound to an Collection of Log4NetLog's, so you can do styling in xaml:

```
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=LogColour.Colour}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Maybe you need a Color to SolidColorBrush Converter.